# "Angular" way of responsive templates? Does matchMedia go in the 'controller'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I'm doing now:
http://jsbin.com/EDovILI/1/edit

Basically sticking an event-listener into the controller. Doesn't feel like the right way to do it, but not sure how this can be abstracted out

The template:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-if="layout == 'big'>...</div>
    <div ng-if="layout == 'small'>...</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function gitReposController($scope, github){
    //...
        var widthQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 44.375em)");
        var setSizeAppropriateTemplate = function (mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                $scope.layout = 'big';
            } else {
                $scope.layout = 'small';
            }
            if(!$scope.$$phase) { //prevents it from unnecessarily calling $scope.$apply when the page first runs
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        };
        widthQuery.addListener(setSizeAppropriateTemplate);
        setSizeAppropriateTemplate(widthQuery);
    //...
}
```

edit/addendum:

Is it bad form to create an event listener in the controller? Should it be a Directive instead? Or maybe a Behavior?

**edit**: modified it into a directive and think it makes more sense now. Could probably be better though.
http://jsbin.com/EDovILI/4/edit

The template:

```
<div ng-app="gitRepos" ng-controller="gitReposController" breakpoint="min-width: 44.375em">
    <div ng-if="matches">...</div>
    <div ng-if="!matches'>...</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript

```
app.directive("breakpoint", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var breakpoint = attrs.breakpoint;
        var mql = window.matchMedia( "(" + breakpoint + ")" );
        var mqlHandler = function (mql) {
            scope.matches = mql.matches;
            if(!scope.$$phase) { //prevents it from unnecessarily calling $scope.$apply when the page first runs
                scope.$apply();
            }
        };
        mql.addListener(mqlHandler);
        mqlHandler(mql);
    };
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it bad form to create an event listener in the controller?
Should it be a Directive instead? Or maybe a Behavior?

Comment: You should use question body for asking what you wish to know. Predicting what is being asked is very hard from just reading the title or a comment buried deep below. For this time, I did that for you. Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious about adding this feature into my Angular projects as well, I've found a few solutions that might help us both:

- [MatchMedia-NG](https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng)
- [Angular Match Media](https://github.com/jacopotarantino/angular-match-media)
- [Angular Adaptive Templating](https://github.com/ghengeveld/angular-adaptive-templating)
- [Angular/Enquire Breakpoints](https://github.com/Bitponics/angular-enquire-breakpoints)

I haven't thoroughly tested any of these approaches so I'm not sure what the "best practice" would be, but it seems these guys had the same thought process as us. Hope this helps!